# Anyway to pre-select exact drop down value? - react js + material ui

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui, dropdown

Consider this

```
render() {

const { gender } = this.state
}

return (
  <div>

            <FormControl variant="outlined">
              <InputLabel>Gender</InputLabel>
              <Select id="dropdown">
                <MenuItem value={10}>Male</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={20}>Female</MenuItem>
              </Select>
            </FormControl>


  </div>
```

When it loads I want just "Male" to be pre-selected since const gender is equal to "Male". E.g. on load it should look like this:

[image]

I've tried putting `document.getElementById("dropdown").selectedIndex = "0";` on componentDidMount but it didn't work. Which usually works in normal select/option

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first entry *should* be selected by default, but if options are in a different order you can specify the default initial value. This can be set as initial state or in any lifecycle function.

Using direct DOM manipulation is a react anti-pattern, stick to using state and/or props to drive the component lifecycle.

```
<Select value={10} id="dropdown">
```

Simple demo

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <select value={30}>
      <option value={10}>Male</option>
      <option value={20}>Female</option>
      <option value={30}>Non-binary</option>
    </select>

    <select>
      <option value={10}>Male</option>
      <option value={20}>Female</option>
      <option value={30}>Non-binary</option>
    </select>

    <select value={10}>
      <option value={10}>Male</option>
      <option value={20}>Female</option>
      <option value={30}>Non-binary</option>
    </select>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="root" />
</body>
```